# Изменение TextView в Tabbed Activity

Tags: java, android, android-fragment

Итак, у меня есть Tabbed Activity с фрагментами. В ней находится одно из окон, которое содержит в своём xml textView, который я программно хочу изменить. Как это реализовать? Перепробовал уже кучу вариантов – не получается.

Tab1.java:

```
public class Tab1 extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       return inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab1mon, container, false);
    }
}
```

Нужны любые рабочие идеи, без разницы как вызывать изменение текста, хоть через кнопку, хоть через onCreate в MainActivity, главное, чтобы это работало.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class Tab1 extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab1mon, container, false);
        TextView tv = v.findViewById(R.id.your_tv);
        tv.setText("Ваш текст");
        return v;
    }
}
```